# Trying to list collection of Firestore Database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to list of the collection of Firestore database inside Ionic4 app so I use the [doc](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections) in the section listCollection so I applied the example code in my code :

```
this.afs.firestore.listCollections().then(collections => {
  for (let collection of collections) {
    console.log(`Found collection with id: ${collection.id}`);
  }
});
```

here is my constructor :

```
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private fireauth: AngularFireAuth) { }
```

And I get this error : error TS2339: Property 'listCollections' does not exist on type 'Firestore'.

I can not use the property listCollections whereas it is in the online doc...

Comment: You're using documentation for `nodejs` ... see [this for documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) for AngularFire

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, as detailed in the Firestore JS SDK [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore), **retrieving a list of collections IS NOT possible with the mobile/web client libraries**.

This is true for the roots collections of your Firestore database but also for the sub-collections of a Firestore document.

However, as you have mentioned in your question, it **IS** possible with the [Cloud Firestore Node.js Client API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/index.html). Therefore you can use a Cloud Function to [list the collections](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections) of your Firestore DB and call this Cloud Function from your front-end.

Since you will call this Cloud Function from your app we use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

### Cloud Function Code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.getCollections = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const collections = await admin.firestore().listCollections();
    const collectionIds = collections.map(col => col.id);

    return { collections: collectionIds };

});
```

### Front-end Code

To call this callable Cloud Function from your Angular app, just follow the Angularfire [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md#creating-a-callable-function) for Cloud Functions.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `{ data$  | async }`
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) { 
    const callable = fns.httpsCallable('getCollections');
    this.data$ = callable({ .... });
  }
}
```

---

Note that this approach is inspired from the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166), which describes how to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document with the JS SDK. *(Disclaimer: I'm the author)*

Comment: Thank you! Do I write those codes inside my Ionic App ?

Comment: The front-end code yes but the Cloud Function code should be used to define a Cloud Function in your own Firebase project: see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series