# Flutter Firebase Loop over collection in a document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this path in my Database:

```
/messages/tT2Q16n1FMZoTNZQOejtWuJdCmD2/ZqihbgR7skcytLAe88fQecmxcIc2-tT2Q16n1FMZoTNZQOejtWuJdCmD2/1579626761580
```

and from here I have to get `content`.

I am trying this:

```
var snapshot = Firestore.instance.collection('messages').document(user.id).snapshots();
```

but how can I loop over these items and get content from each collection?

And then in my UI I want to print this content message:

```
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Content: ${document['content']}',
                  style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0),
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The client-side SDKs for Firestore have no way to request a list of collections. For this reason you'll either need to name your collections in a way that you can embed in your code already, or use one of the Admin SDKs to get a list of collection names and expose that to your client-side code in some way (for example through Cloud Functions).

Also see:

- [Fetching all collections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore)
- [Trying to list collection of Firestore Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993098/trying-to-list-collection-of-firestore-database)
- [How to list subcollections in a Cloud Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596532/how-to-list-subcollections-in-a-cloud-firestore-document)
- [Using Flutter Firestore plug in, do something for each sub collection in a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122019/using-flutter-firestore-plug-in-do-something-for-each-sub-collection-in-a-docum/59127604#59127604)