# Retrieve the list of Sub Collection from Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of sub-collections in flutter I need the names of the subcollections alone how can I get that?

[This is the structure of my firestore.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOGHp.png)

I need the list like:
[name1, name2,.....] to display in a listview in a flutter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no web or mobile client APIs for listing subcollections.  You can only do that using a backend SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59850965/1272655

There currently is no way to get a list of collections through the client sdk.

Comment: Sir, there is no function called get collection.